# Factor of determinant with identical row

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, factoring

How the following fact applies to determinants (I came across it while solving problems):

> Consider A is a nxn matrix, the elements of which are real (or complex) polynomials in x. If r rows of the determinant become identical when x = a, then the determinant has a factor of order < r.

The only additional information I found in the solutions key is that

> (x-a)$^{r-1}$ is a factor of det. A.

Can I know how logically connected is collapsing of rows of matrix (into one row) with order of its factors.

Am I missing some stupid fact here?

Comment: Notice that $\dfrac{d^sA(a)}{dx}=0$ for $0\leq s\leq r-1$ then $A(x)=(x-a)^{r-1}q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$.

Comment: Sorry but I really didnt get it. Can u elaborate please. Am quite a bit poor at maths. :(

Comment: Hi awellwicher. I tried to simplify the solution. Now it only requires some properties of the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited this post. Now the solution is much simpler. It only uses some properties of the determinant.

Let $L_1(x),\ldots,L_n(x)$ be the rows of $A(x)$ and
let us write $A(x)=(L_1(x),\ldots,L_n(x))$. Assume $L_1(a)=\ldots=L_{k}(a)$

Let $B(x)$ be the matrix obtained from $A(x)$ subtracting the first row of $A(x)$ from the rows   $2,3,\ldots,k$. Using our notation, we have $B(x)=(L_1(x),L_2(x)-L_1(x),\ldots,L_k(x)-L_1(x), L_{k+1}(x),\ldots,L_n(x))$.

Now, by property 13 of the determinant [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant), $det(B(x))=det(A(x))$.

Next, the rows $2,3,\ldots,k$ of $B(a)$ are zero. Thus the coefficients $B_{ij}(x)$ of $B(x)$, for $2\leq i\leq k$ and $1\leq j\leq n$, have one root equal to $a$. Thus, we can write $B_{ij}(x)=(x-a)q_{ij}(x)$, where $q_{ij}(x)$ is a polynomial.

Now, since the determinant is a linear function on the rows and the rows $2,3,\ldots,k$ of $B(x)$ are all multiplied by $(x-a)$, we obtain $det(B(x))=(x-a)^{k-1}det(C(x))$, where $C(x)=(L_1(x),\frac{L_2(x)-L_1(x)}{(x-a)},\ldots,\frac{L_k(x)-L_1(x)}{x-a}, L_{k+1}(x),\ldots,L_n(x))$.

Since $C(x)$ is a matrix with polynomial coordinates then $det(C(x))$ is a polynomial and we obtained the result.